# How to set up a dd-wrt router, isolating one ethernet port from the rest

Tags: networking

I had this setup running some time ago, but it seems to have lost some setting and I can not find the original instructions anymore:

I have a dd-wrt router with 4 Ethernet ports. I want to configure it so that one ethernet port only has normal (non-dmz) access to the internet, and the rest of the connections (3 ethernet and the wlan) to be able to see each other.

I already had VLANs configured, but when I connect my device to the isolated port, it does not get a DHCP address any more. Where do I configure which ports are assigned DHCP addresses? Failing that, does anyone have a link to the correct howto?

Comment: Belongs on Superuser.com maybe?

Comment: I pondered putting it there, but it is (imho) too specific and techy to get the desired answer there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VLAN_Detached_Networks_(Separate_Networks_With_Internet)) may help. The instruction seem quite detailed including dhcp on multiple interfaces.

Comment: Ah, there it is. Thanks, that was what I was searching for.